# I want to remove Time Stamp and dateline from date entries

Tags: date, merge, timestamp, google-apps-script

I copy and pasted the mail merge script from a third party source. It works terrifically except for one thing.

When I type a date into my form (ex. July 7, 2012) the script in the mail merge converts the date into a dateline (ex. July 7, 2012 00:00:00 GMT).

I want to remove the unnecessary date after the date. Can you help me?

here is the portion of the code that is the most relevant to this problem:
      // Setup the current timestamp and timezone.
     timeZone = myVariablesSheet.getRange("B13").getValue();
      dateline = myVariablesSheet.getRange("B7").getValue();

```
  if(typeof timeZone == 'undefined' || timeZone == '') {
    timeZone = 'GMT';
  }
  if(typeof dateline == 'undefined' || dateline == '') {
    dateline = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timeZone, "EEE, MMM d, ''yy");
  } else {
    dateline = Utilities.formatDate(dateline, timeZone, "EEE, MMM d, ''yy");
  }
  if(debug) Browser.msgBox("dateline = " + dateline + "\ntimeZone = " + timeZone);
```

Comment: Is the 'long value' the value shown in the Browser.msg box or in  the sheets cell? The browser.msg should be correct!  If it is only the cell value that shows the wrong way than you can fix that in the format of the cell from the sheet format menu.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are asking how to format a date.

If you want the date formatted as July 9, 2012 you'd need enter this 'MMMM d, yyyy'.

Like this:

```
Logger.log(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'PST', 'MMMM d, yyyy'))
```